# Read value of element inside each div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this chunk of code

```
$('.order_box').each(function(index) {
    box=$(this);
    if(box.find('.order_status').val()=="Payment received") { 
        box.css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

which is supposed to read the value of selects contained in a bunch of divs and apply a css style to each div accordingly. The div html is:

```
<div class="order_box">
<h1>Order nr.: 2329268704685016576</h1>
<div class="delivery_info">
    --
    <span class="titles">Status:
        <select class="order_status">
            <option class="payment_received" value="Payment received">Payment received</option>
            <option class="need_refund" value="Need to refund money">Need to refund money</option>
            <option class="waiting_stock" value="Waiting for product/s stock">Waiting for product/s stock</option>
            <option class="packing" value="Packing">Packing</option>
            <option class="delivered" value="Delivered/Done" selected="selected">Delivered/Done</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    --
</div>
```

I'm assuming I might be applying the each function in a wrong way, but of course I can't get why. I'm in the hope to get what's wrong with my usage, as it's not the first time I find myself in such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('.order_box').each(function(index) {
        var box = $(this);
        if($('.order_status :selected', this).val() == "Payment received") {
           box.css('color', 'red');
        }
    })
```

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHA7e/) example.

Comment: Sounds good, the fiddle is missing a </div> to close the first .order_box, but this works as I was looking for. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Now you're looping through all elements with the class .order_box. I assume you want to check the value of .order_status ?

```
if($('.order_status').val() == 'Payment received') {
    $('.order_box').css('color', 'red');
}
```

If you need different rules for each outcome, you could wrap it in a switch.

```
switch($('order_status').val()) {
    case 'Payment received':
         $('.order_box').css('color', 'red');
         break;

    case 'Need to refund money':
         $('.order_box').css('color', 'green');
         break;

    // etc etc
}
```

I don't see why you would use $.each here.

Comment: I think the each is because there is going to be multiple `.order_box`s

Comment: Yes, 'cause there are more than one .order_box, I'm sorry if I didn't articulate my question really well. :)
But thank you for the switch trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a little to:

```
$('.order_box').addClass(function(){
    return $(this).find('.order_status').val().trim().toLowerCase() == 'payment received' ? 'classNameIfMatch' : '';
});
```

Using `trim()` to remove any leading/trailing white-spaces from the value, and `toLowerCase()` in order to prevent capitalisation-errors (in the HTML or the jQuery) from causing problems.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6cB4u/1/).

Interestingly enough this approach is somewhat faster/more efficient than the accepted answer: [JS Perf comparison of approaches](http://jsperf.com/alternate-jquery-styling-approaches), though note that I chose to amend the code of the accepted answer so that, in both cases, the same CSS properties were being set.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/trim/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: I'm going to save this, I'm not concerned much about trim/uppercase-lowercase issues as I exactly know the values will be written like that but that's really good to know how to handle it in case of need.

Comment: @Paprika: I'm glad to have been of some help, though please note that your accepted answer is, according to [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/alternate-jquery-styling-approaches) 79% slower than my own suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the link to JS Perf, that's a really handy and informative tool (which I wasn't aware of its existence). I couldn't have imagine that the performance could be so highly improved using your code. I choosed the actual accepted answer as it was what I was looking for, but I recognize this approach is more clever and good-looking (considering it also checks capitals issues/white spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Since your code only depends on the order_status class, the each function is not needed.

Use the jQuery Api http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/ correctly.

```
$(".order_status").change(function(){
if($(".order_status option:selected").val()=="Payment received") { 
$(this).attr('style','color:red;');
}else{
$(this).attr('style','color:black;');
}
});
```

Check the problem resolved here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hunkyhari/Q9Zfc/

Comment: The action needs to fire on document.ready(), and also on change, I was still on the first part of the problem. But thank you, I can still adapt this for the second part.